# Create JSON tree with unknown root

Tags: python, json, minimum-spanning-tree

I have the following data created from a minimum spanning tree algorithm:

```
links = [("Earl","Bob"),("Bob","Sam"),("Bob","Leroy"),("Leroy","Harry")]
```

I need to convert the data into the following json tree:

```
{
    "id": "Earl",
    "name": "Earl",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "Bob",
            "name": "Bob",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "Leroy",
                    "name": "Leroy",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": "Harry",
                            "name": "Harry"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "Sam",
                    "name": "Sam"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have the following script which works except that it adds a root node called 'Root' to the tree which I do not want:

```
import json
links = [("Earl","Bob"),("Bob","Sam"),("Bob","Leroy"),("Leroy","Harry")]
parents, children = zip(*links)
root_nodes = {x for x in parents if x not in children}
for node in root_nodes:
    links.append(('Root', node))

def get_nodes(node):
    d = {}
    d['id'] = node
    d['name'] = node
    children = get_children(node)
    if children:
        d['children'] = [get_nodes(child) for child in children]
    return d

def get_children(node):
    return [x[1] for x in links if x[0] == node]

tree = get_nodes('Root')
print(json.dumps(tree, indent=2))   

### output below  ###

{
  "children": [
    {
      "children": [
        {
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "Sam",
              "name": "Sam"
            },
            {
              "children": [
                {
                  "id": "Harry",
                  "name": "Harry"
                }
              ],
              "id": "Leroy",
              "name": "Leroy"
            }
          ],
          "id": "Bob",
          "name": "Bob"
        }
      ],
      "id": "Earl",
      "name": "Earl"
    }
  ],
  "id": "Root",
  "name": "Root"
}
```

What I need is to not add a fake 'Root' as the root node. The root should simply be any existing node in `links` which does not have a parent (as per the first json example). In other words, the root of the tree doesn't necessarily have to be Earl, it can be any of the nodes which do not have parents. The tree can then start expanding from there.

Perhaps there's a better algorithm for doing this instead of trying to modify this?

Answer (score -1):

```
tree = get_nodes('Root');
tree = tree.children[0];
print(json.dumps(tree, indent=2));
```

Comment: tree = tree.children[0] results in: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'children'

Comment: yeah sorry, forgot python syntax a bit.
`tree = tree.get("children")[0]`

Answer (score -1):

Isn't this because you've added Earl as a child of Root? With:

```
links.append(('Root', node))
print links # [('Earl', 'Bob'), ('Bob', 'Sam'), ('Bob', 'Leroy'), ('Leroy', 'Harry'), ('Root', 'Earl')]
```

So now when you run `children = get_children(node)` for `node = 'Root'`, you'll get `True`.

Comment: Yes that is the issue. However I don't know how to do this so that there is no 'Root' as the root node. The root needs to be any node which doesn't have a parent. I just used Earl as an example. any suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: Can you get the contents of the child node? Something like `print(json.dumps(tree['children'], indent=2))`?